# habitat-api quick start not running properly - qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, artificial-intelligence

I am currently trying to run the example from [habitat-api](https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-api/blob/master/docs/pages/quickstart.rst) but when I run the example it doesn't run properly.

I fixed one issue that was not updated in the code (`"pointgoal"` should be `"pointgoal_with_gps_compass"`)

This is what the terminal gives me after running `python testActions.py`:

```
2020-03-13 17:29:37,024 Initializing dataset PointNav-v1
2020-03-13 17:29:37,217 initializing sim Sim-v0
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0313 17:29:37.234107 303062464 SceneGraph.h:92] Created DrawableGroup: 
Renderer: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics 640 by Intel Inc.
OpenGL version: 4.1 INTEL-14.4.23
Using optional features:
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic
    GL_ARB_texture_storage
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
    GL_EXT_debug_label
    GL_EXT_debug_marker
Using driver workarounds:
    no-layout-qualifiers-on-old-glsl
I0313 17:29:37.395491 303062464 ResourceManager.cpp:1072] Importing Basis files as BC3
W0313 17:29:38.644949 303062464 Simulator.cpp:140] :
---
 The active scene does not contain semantic annotations. 
---
I0313 17:29:38.651930 10376 simulator.py:142] Loaded navmesh data/scene_datasets/habitat-test-scenes/skokloster-castle.navmesh
2020-03-13 17:29:38,737 Initializing task Nav-v0
Environment creation successful
Destination, distance: 5.883259, theta(radians): -0.00
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

zsh: abort      python testActions.py
```

<strike>I think there is some issue in the code.</strike> I have tried to ask on the GitHub repository ([issue #330](https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-api/issues/330)) <s>but still waiting to see if the error is there.</s> I have been told that the error is with my installation of OpenCV.

Comment: Do you have Qt installed?

Comment: I guess I don't... I am following the instructions from https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-api/blob/master/docs/pages/quickstart.rst

Comment: after doing `brew install qt` i still have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using an older version of `opencv-python`

```
pip unistall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python==4.1.0.25
```